# Banana Pro: Error con LMK.GPIO

Tags: python

Agradezco si alguien puede ayudarme con este inconveniente.
Instalo  LMK.GPIO  (una versión de RPi.GPIO para placas de LeMaker) y al intentar ejecutar el código de ejemplo en Python (clásico Blink) No ejecuta y me devuelve el siguiente eror: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'BOARD'

El código de ejemplo es el siguiente:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import LMK.GPIO as GPIO
import time
#LED Mode BOARD
PIN_NUM = 7
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
while True:
try:
    GPIO.setup(PIN_NUM, GPIO.OUT)
except:
    print("Failed to setup GPIO %d", PIN_NUM)
GPIO.output(PIN_NUM, True)
time.sleep(0.5)
GPIO.output(PIN_NUM, False)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: Dice que no tiene el atributo ```BOARD``` revisa la documentación tal vez algo a cambiado

Comment: Hola Néstor. Puede ser que el módulo BOARD no exista más, y hayan cambiado su nombre por otro, o quizás el programa no lee bien el código. Puedes intentar importar directamente BOARD, y leer la documentación para ver si no hay algún error en tu código.